# Translate Android Studio Java code to Objective-C with j2objc,Is it possible?

Tags: j2objc

I've tested j2objc by translating simple HelloWorld Java code to Objective-C, and that's ok.
Next, I've tried to convert Java code that was written in adroid studio with GUI translate to Objective-C. But it doesn't work and give me [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxkxY.png). How can I translate android studio java code to Objective-C, or something else that can be accessed with iOS?
Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to accomplish this in the first place?

Comment: sure! I've written an application with android Studio. It's OK on android based systems. Now I want to access it on iOS system. because of that I  need a translator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI code is explicitly not supported by j2objc; the first paragraph on http://j2objc.org states:

> The goal is to write an app's non-UI code (such as application logic
>   and data models) in Java, which is then shared by web apps (using
>   GWT), Android apps, and iOS apps.

AFAIK, there is no tool that converts Android UI to iOS. There are, however, several platforms that have their own UI abstraction which support Android and iOS, such as [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com), [Corona SDK](https://coronalabs.com/) and [Apache Cordova (aka Phonegap)](http://cordova.apache.org/).